# Virtuemart Mobile & desktop on the same server

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

How could i install Virtuemart Mobile & desktop on the same  Joomla server?

Is this possible?

I install the both templates template i could only show one on the same time.

Joomla 3.**
Virtuemart 2.**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new menu for mobile users and assign the template using:

```
Menus -> *Mobile_Menu -> *Menu_item -> Template Style
```

Hope this helps